# What's the RESTful Rails route for this nested import page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to obey the Rails RESTful routes approach. I have two kinds of resources:

- data
- repositories

Data belongs to repositories. Unlike a typical ActiveRecord application I don't use HTML forms to create these resources. Instead both entities are serialized in YAML files which I upload to persist them into my database.

Since a small import page does not take up much space and for convenience I would like to put both importer on one page.

```
+------------------------------+
| <Import Repositories>        |
+------------------------------+

+------------------------------+
| Repository A - <Import Data> |
+------------------------------+
| Repository B - <Import Data> |
+------------------------------+
| ...                          |
```

But what is the appropriate route in this case here?

Just `/repositories/new` or something like `repositories/data/new` ?

How would I go for this, respectively what is the shortest way of defining this in `routes.rb`. The repositories are moddeled through classes, the data not (to keep it general). So maybe

```
resource repositories
```

is just fine?

Answer (score 0):

As for me it is ok. Repository is a main entity, data belongs to it. It is similar to view with accept_nested_attributes form.